# Id based crawling with Nutch2.x with HBase -> SolrIndexerJob not working

Tags: solr, hbase, nutch

I am using Nutch2.x with hbase 0.90.6 and the first strange thing I have noticed is that it is creating its 'webpage' table with prefix of crawlId i.e. if my crawlId is C1 then it creates table as 'C1_webpage' , which I think should not be. But it is doing so and my nutch jobs [ Inject -> Generate -> Fetch -> Parse -> DBUpdate ] are running fine.

Now problem I am facing is that with this setup and 'C1_webpage' table , SolrIndexjob is not inserting any document to Solr , because I think it looks for docs in 'webpage' table which always have 0 rows and actual data is in 'C1_webpage'.

How should I solve my this problem ? 
Any one is using nutch2.x with hbase 0.90.6 and doing Id based crawling ?

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run solrIndexerJob with script below by crawlId. This will index only C1_webpage table.

```
bin/nutch solrindex http://localhost:8983/solr -all -crawlId C1
```